# How to add new plugin like Autocomplete in CK classic editor 5 used in ASP .net core mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, plugins, autocomplete, ckeditor5

Here I integrate classic CK-Editor in View of C# file.I am trying to add new autocomplete plugin in classic editor.

```
    <div class="card-body areacls cardBox" contenteditable="true" id="@areaId" data-href="@item.Id" onclick="createEditor(@areaId)">
                            @Html.Raw(item.Description)
                        </div>
    <script>
    var editors = new Map();
    function createEditor(elementToReplace) {
    
                return ClassicEditor
                    .create(elementToReplace)
                    .then(editor => {
                        editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);
    
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use`F12` to see if any error message in your console.

I guess you miss the `<script>`,refer to [ckeditor.com] :(https://cdn.ckeditor.com/)

> To start using CKEditor 5 Builds on your website, add a single
> `<script>` tag to your HTML page:

add below code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/37.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: there is no error in console. I am just asking about how to add new plugin in classic editor.

Answer (score 0):

In classic Editor 5 version has some builtin plugins. you can't add new plugins in 5 version.If you want to use new plugin like **mention** you have to create your own custom editor from here https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ or you can change the predefined builds like **Classic,Inline,Balloon,Balloon-block,Document,Multi-root,Superbuild.**